# Neutral and ground wire switched

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I want to change my over stove microwave single outlet to a 2 outlet plug. When pulling out the old outlet, I see that the white wire is attached to the green screw and the bare copper wire is attached to the silver screw. Is this a mistake? Should I install the new plug like it is supposed to be , or like they did it? This is a newly built house.

Larry

Comment: Yeah, that's a huge mistake.  There is no way that can be not a mistake.

Comment: check a few of the other outlets in your house ..... the electrician may be incompetent

Comment: In many jurisdictions the microwave must have its own dedicated circuit.  If there is a single outlet plug you probably should not be replacing it with a dual.

Answer (score 3):

We can assume that the mistake starts and ends in that box, but there are other considerations. If the outlet is fed from a sub-panel, neutral and ground aren't (or shouldn't be) bonded. If they're also reversed there, reversing the connections at the outlet could be dangerous.

If you're confident that you're working with conventional wiring served from the primary service panel, go ahead and make the switch. Otherwise, consult a local expert. I'd have a look at a few more outlets in the area to see if there's a trend.

Also be aware that if you're working with a 15A circuit, the microwave likely consumes all available current. You won't have any overhead for other devices without causing nuisance trips.